# Why does to_bytes(2, byteorder="big") return sometimes only one byte?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex, byte

I really don't understand why does sometimes to_bytes return not what I want.
For instance, here is an expected behavior :

```
i = 12
i.to_bytes(2, byteorder="big")
>> b'\x00\x0c'
```

However, here is sometimes the output :

```
i = 870
i.to_bytes(2, byteorder="big")
>> b'\x03f'
```

while I would like to have :

```
>> b'\x03\x66'
```

Does anyone have any clue ? Is there another way to obtain what I want ?
Thanks a lot !

I tried other method with format, hex, ... but I really want bytes in hexadecimal format with '\x' ...

Comment: The string that you see is just how python tries to be "helpful" and renders the two bytes as: `"\x03"` and `"f"`. Another option is to use `hex(i)` which will produce `"0x366"`.

Comment: That's just how `bytes` strings display themselves. The `f` is the ASCII equivalent of `\x66`.

Answer (score 1):

The method `to_bytes()` (in your case) produces a byte array of length 2. It renders however python wants to render it.

If you want it printed differently, you can convert it to a string like this:

```py
i = 12
byts = i.to_bytes(2, byteorder="big")
out = ''.join(f'\\x{b:02x}' for b in byts)
print(out)
```

Output:

`\x03\x66`

Note that the output is a string and not a byte array.